# Stuck in power saving mode

Tags: multiple-monitors, powersave

I've got an LG monitor I tried attaching to my laptop for dual monitor goodness and it worked fine but when I tried attaching it back to the desktop it stuck in "Power Saving mode" and wouldn't go away.  The CPU's starting up but nothing happens with the monitor. I try attaching it back to the laptop and it works fine again.  I don't understand what could have happened.

For reference, the laptop I'm using is an HP laptop with nVidia GT240M video card running on an i7 processor while the desktop runs on a Dual Core processor with an nVidia 9400GT video card.

I've never had problems like these with other monitors I've attached my pc to. Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry. More stupidity than anything. Plugged the cable to the internal graphics card rather than the video card. T_T

Answer (score 0):

It's a wild guess, but maybe your graphics card came loose? That's the only idea I could have for why. The problem *is* your graphics card/desktop though. If the monitor works with your laptop, then your monitor is good.